# Get next, higher value based on current value

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, window-functions

I'm trying to get the next audit id from a log but am getting multiple NextAuditID's  for each AuditID.

A couple of questions:

1. how can this be corrected?
2. is this the most efficient approach?

My code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    AuditID, MIN(NextAuditID) NextAuditID
FROM
    (SELECT 
         SMStart.AuditID AuditID, SMNext.AuditID NextAuditID
     FROM 
         SchedulerMetrics SMStart,
         SchedulerMetrics SMNext
     WHERE 
         SMStart.Message = SMNext.Message
         AND SMNext.AuditID > SMStart.AuditID) tt
GROUP BY 
    AuditID, NextAuditID
```

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are argumenst to set functions. I.e try `GROUP BY AuditID`.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `LEAD` window function:

```
SELECT AuditID, LEAD(AuditID) OVER (PARTITION BY Message ORDER BY AuditID) AS NextAuditID
FROM SchedulerMetrics
```

Comment: Thank you Salman for the quick response, very much appreciated, Rod